# How to stop post back of particular panel reside in grid view row using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# asp.net i am already implemented selecting the row  by clicking any where on the that  and doing post back  but now i have to put text box it so  i have to stop post back  for particular control `text box click`  How can i achieve this.
My Aspx code is:
 in Grid view row data bound

```
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvdetails,"Select$"+e.Row.RowIndex);

            }
}
```

If i comment this line my requirement working fine so how can i stop Click for that text box:

Approaches i followed
1. Particular text box `autopostback=false`;
2. `Onclientclick="return false"` on that text box but these two are not worked for. please help me. i am struggling with this from three days.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: So you dont want to comment this line and still stop postback on its click ?

Comment: Ya exactly I want to stop post back only when text box is click on that row.